# Passing a URL as a varible via mod rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to pass a actual url as a varible using mod_rewrite on apache

I have a page externalLink.php that can be passed a url in oder to do some magic i.e.

/externalLink.php?url=http://example.com

I wnat this to be a nice url like /external/http://example.com

I have added a rewrite rule to my htaccess that I hope might work, but as a suspected it does not.

RewriteRule ^external/([^/.]+)/*$ /externalLink.php?url=$1 [L]

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Thanks in advance

.k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /external/(http://[^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^external/http:/ externalLink.php?url=%1 [L]
```

You need to examine `THE_REQUEST` as Apache strips empty path segments in the URL path.

Comment: Hey Gumbo,

Thats great !

.k

Answer (score 1):

there will occur problems with the slashes in http://

try:

```
RewriteRule ^external/(^http:\/\/.+)/$ /externalLink.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Following to your explanation, you forgot to escape the first slash in your regular expression. But that’s not necessary at all. This is not Perl or any other language where regular expressions have delimiters that need to be escaped.